# Tooltip adorner

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using a third party charting library (Infragistics xamChart).  I am not satisfied with how tooltips are displayed on a line charts datapoints so I was thinking of using an adorner to make a better looking/interactive tooltip.

What I want to do is have the adorner popup whenever one of the datapoints is hovered over.  Does anyone have any pointers on how I can do this?  Most of the adorner samples I found are pretty simple ones that just alter the entire control they are adorning.

My main questions are:

- Is it possible for an adorner to
  appear only when certain elements are
  hovered over (and have it appear at
  the current cursor position)?
- Does anyone have a simple sample they
  can share?
- Are adorners the right way to go
  here?  I think the only other option
  was to use the popup control but I
  though adorners were a nicer
  solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `Attached Behaviours` could help you? From this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx):

> The idea is that you set an attached
>   property on an element so that you can
>   gain access to the element from the
>   class that exposes the attached
>   property. Once that class has access
>   to the element, it can hook events on
>   it.

That way you could attach a listener to the `MouseEnter` event and display your custom `ToolTip` from there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.  But it seems that ToolTip won't work for me.  I want the ToolTip to contain a button and textBox but it doesn't look like the controls on tooltip can be interacted with.  Are adorners or popups my best bet?

Comment: You don't have to use a `ToolTip` control. Once you have attached your listeners and the user triggers them by moving their mouse, you will have access to the object and be able to display anything you like over the top of it. I fear that you may not be able to get access to the individual elements in the chart though.

Comment: (You would need to use the `Attached Behaviour` on the individual chart elements for this method to work).

Comment: Yeah, that's my question.  How would I display my desired controls and set their location?  That's why I was thinking of using adorners but I am not sure how to set one up to appear when an event is triggered at a specific location.

Comment: Ahhh, my mistake. You could try to access the chart elements by looping through the visual elements of the chart using the `VisualTreeHelper` class. [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx)